# Slanted text problem for the main (cmr) font in XeLaTeX with fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, slanted

I'm newbie in XeLaTeX and have to adopt already typeset (in LaTeX) textbook with the Computer Modern Roman mainfont. So I want to have slanted text, while the compiler with default introduction (taken somewhere)

```
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif Roman}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}  
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
```

(and latex-preserved commands `\textsl{}` and `\slshapr` for the usage)
writes that slanted text is replaced by the simple italic.

I tried in two ways: (I) load the font cmunsl.otf as overall-windows-installed and tried to use it as independent new font:

```
\font\wslant="CMU Serif Extra RomanSlanted" at 12pt
```

(II) In the fontspec documentation (p.11) I found that the slanted font can be added as an option to the `\setmainfont`; I tried (a)

```
\setmainfont[SlantedFont = CMU Serif Extra RomanSlanted]{CMU Serif Roman}
```

and (b)

```
\setmainfont[SlantedFont = cmunsl.otf]{CMU Serif Roman}
(this OTF-file cmunsl.otf is presented in the folder
C:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\fonts\opentype\public\cm-unicode\)
```

In all cases the error is 'your font is not found'. The same if I declare Path explicitly: `\setmainfont[Path=...,SlantedFont =...]`

Could anybody help with proper font declaration and proper usage in the text?
In the questions with tag 'slanted' I did not found the solution for the main font family.

Thanks

Comment: @Akira Kakuto
It works! Many thanks. I have found the font indentifications in the Net. Probably those were valid for Linux

Answer (score 2):

Use fullname obtained by

```
fc-list : file fullname

\setmainfont[SlantedFont=CMU Serif Roman Slanted]{CMU Serif Roman}
```

must be ok.

```
\setmainfont[SlantedFont=[cmunsl.otf]]{CMU Serif Roman}
```

may also be ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you can call the fonts by system name, the simplest is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif Roman}[
  SlantedFont=CMU Serif Roman Slanted,
]

\begin{document}

Normal, \textit{italic}, \textsl{slanted}.

\end{document}
```

Otherwise you need to specify all font file names:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\setmainfont{cmun}[
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *rm,
  BoldFont       = *bx,
  ItalicFont     = *ti,
  BoldItalicFont = *bi,
  SlantedFont    = *sl,
]

\begin{document}

Normal, \textit{italic}, \textsl{slanted}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` is not to be used with XeLaTeX. Also

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
```

is not needed, because the `Ligatures=TeX` option is set by default and `Renderer=Basic` does nothing with XeLaTeX.